# Prove that for two vectors x,y over GF(q), the number of vectors that are closer to x is the same as the number of vectors that closer to y.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, metric-spaces, finite-fields, coding-theory

> Let $x,y\in\mathbb F_q^n$ be vectors. We'll define:
>
> $X= \{ u\in\mathbb F_q^n \mid d(x,u)<d(y,u)\}$
>
> $Y= \{ u\in\mathbb F_q^n \mid d(y,u)<d(x,u)\}$
>
> Prove that $|X|=|Y|$.

Well. I tried really hard and I really don't know. I tried using the sphere packing bound for proving something, but of course the the code $C=\{x,y\}$ is not perfect, so it won't help.

I tried constructing a linear code $C=\operatorname{span}\{x,y\}$ and use the Lagrange theorem for cosets (That says: All $q^n$ vectors are in one of the coests of $C$; each coset have same number of words; and all not-equal cosets are disjoint), but i don't know how to use it, because the code is $q$-ary, so this code have more words than $x,y$ in this code (so i can't do anything).

Thanks.

Comment: What is your metric $d$?

Comment: @NicholasR.Peterson: The question is tagged coding theory, so it's probably the Hamming metric (number of distinct entries).

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Proof that
$$f : \mathbb F_q^n \to \mathbb F_q^n,\quad v\mapsto v - x + y$$
induces a bijection $X \to Y$.

Comment: +1 Indeed. The Hamming space has this group of isometries (w.r.t. the Hamming metric) acting transitively :-)